# Select&autofill cells on multiple sheets - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to autofill data in cells `$A$5:$A$37` in every worksheet named "`Arbeitsblatt XX`".
I was able to get some code for the autofill part as well as for repeating in every worksheet.
Sources:

- https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3974-excel-repeat-a-value-until-new-value-is-seen.html#a3
- http://www.herber.de/forum/archiv/1584to1588/1586203_mehrere_Tabellenblaetter_zusammenfuehren.html
  (German)

Now, combining my coding templates was almost successful. I only was able to autofill on the sheet including the related button OR just like now, as you might see in the following code, I am able to select all the relevant cells in every sheet but without the autofill.

I guess it has something to do with a missing reference to the worksheet, but I am too stupid to detect. Thanks for your help.

```
            Sub FillDown()
            Dim xRng As Range
            Dim xRows As Long, xCols As Long
            Dim xRow As Integer, xCol As Integer

            Dim wsQ As Worksheet

            Set xRng = Selection
            Set currws = ActiveSheet

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False


            For Each wsQ In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

             If Left(wsQ.Name, 12) = "Arbeitsblatt" Then
                    With wsQ
                     wsQ.Activate
                Cells(5, 1).Resize(33, 1).Select

                xCols = xRng.Columns.CountLarge
                xRows = xRng.Rows.CountLarge
            For xCol = 1 To xCols
              For xRow = 1 To xRows - 1
                If xRng.Cells(xRow, xCol) <> "" Then
                  xRng.Cells(xRow, xCol) = xRng.Cells(xRow, xCol).Value
                  If xRng.Cells(xRow + 1, xCol) = "" Then
                    xRng.Cells(xRow + 1, xCol) = xRng.Cells(xRow, xCol).Value
                  End If
                End If
              Next xRow
            Next xCol
            currws.Activate

                     End With
                End If
            Next wsQ

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            End Sub
```

Comment: What is `xRng`?

Comment: xRng would be A5:A37 in every worksheet, the range where autofill should be applied

Answer (score 0):

I am sad to see there is no answer or advice for your question yet. Please let me try to help.

I like simple codes therefore I have tried to use `.AutoFill` method which Excel provides. Please see code below which I have tested on a sample Workbook:

```
Sub FillDown()
Dim wsQ As Worksheet

    For Each wsQ In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If Left(wsQ.Name, 12) = "Arbeitsblatt" Then
            With wsQ
            .Activate
            .Range("A5").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A5:A37") 'this is the autofill which starts autofilling from A5 cell and ends in A37 cell
            .Range("A5:A37").Select
            End With
        End If
    Next wsQ

End Sub
```

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to autofill, therefore this simple code might or might not be sufficient. If you could provide more information (for example what data are you trying to autofill and if it always starts at A5 or if the cells can be half filled already and you just need to finish the rest etc.)

Please let me know the results so me or others can further help. Thank you.

Comment: Of course you can then create a named range and declare it as xRng as I saw in the comments, I wanted to make it as transparent as possible to be easy to understand.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to copy to the next column

Comment: Thanks very much, Jan! Could you also let me know, how to adjust your code (works perfectly btw) so that I can autofill while having multiple values in that range?
Sorry, I could have mentioned that earlier, this is also why my code is so weird and long.

A little example:
source: 
A
-
B
- 
current:
A
A
A
A
goal:
A
A
B
B